# Loop through list of values mapped to a single key to create new list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, dictionary

given a dictionary:

```
somedictionary = {"a":["b","c","d"],"1":["2","3"]}
```

how can i create separate lists such that `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` and `['1', '2', '3']` are two separate lists? My trouble with this is looping through the list of key values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `items`

```
w_dict = {"a":["b","c","d"],"1":["2","3"]}

lists = [[k] + v for k,v in w_dict.items()]
```

yields:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['1', '2', '3']]
```